# Problem with integration facebook sdk into unity

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to integrate fb sdk into my project, I do everything according to the official documentation. after I failed, I decided to watch the video on integration and read the forums, I found several questions with the same error, but they were left unanswered.

All in all my problem looks like this:

Logs:[image]
Services (after integrating the SDK with the services tab, something strange happened):[image]

The same situation with project settings:[image]

Before that I integrated AdMob, In-APP, AppMetrica and Vibration. Ask your questions, I will be glad to supplement the question and I will be glad for any help! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, in short, when integrating, there was no need to import PlayServicesResolver folder [image]

After import, a window should have appeared that would have deleted this folder, but I did not have such a window

There were a few more errors, but they will not occur if you do not import this folder. I logged into my fb account and now all submissions come